# How to get Translation using Frame ARCore?

Tags: java, android, arcore

I am working on a AR project that was old and I am updating it. This uses ARCore. I am able to update all functions but am confused only at one point.
Earlier, I could use the current frame and get a rotation and translation on that using the following lines:

arFrame.getPose().getTranslation(translation, 0);
arFrame.getPose().getRotationQuaternion(rotation, 0);

But now I think the getTranslation() and getRotationQuanternion() has moved under Pose for ARCore. So, how do I use this for a frame?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ARCore APIs may have changed slightly if your project was created with one of the SDK previews. The current pose is now associated with the `Camera` instead of the `Frame`. You can access the pose by getting a reference to the camera first:

```
Camera camera = arFrame.getCamera();
Pose pose = camera.getPose();
pose.getTranslation(translation, 0);
pose. getRotationQuaternion(rotation, 0);
```

Do note though that this is only useful if the `Camera`'s current tracking state is `TRACKING`, so you may want to check that before extracting the `Pose`: https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/Camera.html#getPose()

Comment: I figured it out but anyways Thanks :)